# How to get specific column value using IBM JPA tools

Tags: java, jpa

Example, I have the table below, i wanted to create a method to get only the CustomerID so that i can use it to refer to the customer table to get more detail about that particular customer. how can I get a specific column value and add it into a String variable. Example, i wanted get a specific customerID and put it into a String variable call custID. In normal java query we can do that by using

`String custNo = resultSet.getString("CustomerID");`

How can i do that with IBM JPA Tools? What is the code i should type to get that particular column value? i tried with .get() .getClass() or .toString() which it does not work.

```
   CREATE TABLE Ordering 
(
    OrderID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID VARCHAR(10),
    OrderDate DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the queries automatically generated by the IDE (RAD) based on your underlying data?
Section "How JPA queries are added" from the following example might be of some help
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/08/0819_mutdosch/

Comment: Yes, the query is generated using the JPA tools, What i wanted to know is how can I get a specific column value and add it into a String variable. Example, i wanted get a specific customerID and put it into a String variable call custID. In normal java query we can do that by using " String custNo = resultSet.getString("CustomerID"); ". How can i do that in Java Persistence?